# Creating An Interactive Timeline

Tags: user-interface, animation, three.js, timeline

I want to build a 3D design program, just like tinkercad. However in this program user can create keyframes and play animation through a timeline in UI.

This is nothing new, many desktop applications can do this (e.g Blender, 3DSMax, AfterFX...). However, I couldn't find an example project or anything that comes handy in documentations. Is it possible to make it happen in three.js?

Comment: Nothing out of the box that I am aware of but I have built simple keyframe/curve editing widgets using html overlaid on a three.js scene...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [GreenSock's GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap), it is a general purpose HTML5 animation library, which can easily be applied to a three.js project. This is a tutorial about [creating Timelines using GSAP](https://greensock.com/position-parameter)

You might also want to check out the [Under Neon Lights editor](https://github.com/within-unlimited/under-neon-lights) which uses [Frame.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/frame.js/)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for! It took me some time to figure out as a begineer, but it works like a charm.